# pub get failed (65 ╵) exit code 65

Tags: dart, pubspec

```
Error on line 1, column 7 of ..\pubspec.yaml: "name" field doesn't match expected name "provider".
  ╷                                                                     
1 │ name: cabdriver
  │       ^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
```

Running "flutter pub get" in example...
pub get failed (65;   ╵)

how to clear this?

Comment: It looks like you have used the wrong project name in your `pubspec.yaml` file.  The message is saying that the YAML file should say `name: provider` rather than `name: cabdriver`.

Comment: Note that the question is not about Java.  It is really about Dart `pubspec.yaml` files.  I have fixed the tags.